# Evaluate $\int^1_0 \arcsin(x)dx$

Tags: integration

I`m trying to evaluate this integral and the answer is $\arcsin(1)-1$
The answer I get is : $x\arcsin(x)+\cos(x)|^{1}_0$
$$\int\limits^1_0 \arcsin(x)dx$$
My solution for this integral is:
$$\int\limits^1_0 \arcsin(x)dx \rightarrow U=\arcsin(x),U'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}},V'=1,V=$$
$$=x\arcsin(x)-\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx \rightarrow x=\sin(t),dx=\cos(t)$$
$$=x\arcsin(x)-\int\frac{\sin(t)\cos(t)}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2(t)}}dt \rightarrow x=\sin(t),dx=\cos(t)$$
$$=x\arcsin(x)-\int\frac{\sin(t)\cos(t)}{\sqrt{\cos^2(t)}}dt$$
$$=x\arcsin(x)-\int\frac{\sin(t)\cos(t)}{\cos(t)}dt$$
$$=x\arcsin(x)-\int\sin(t)dt$$
$$=x\arcsin(x)+\cos(t)|^{1}_{0} $$ 
I dont know if my problem is here. the last line,I should change the values by $t$ or I can keep the values of $x$
Thanks!

Comment: By the way, the second integral is faster if you let $u=1-x^2$.

Comment: Yea, I know, I just wanted to solve it in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must change the limits of $t$ in the last line from 0 to $\frac{\pi}{2}$:

Answer (score 2):

Your hunch about needing to change the limits of integration when evaluating $\cos t$ at the very end are correct:

You initially put $x = \sin t$ here:

$$=x\arcsin(x)-\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx \rightarrow \color{blue}{\bf x=\sin(t)},dx=\cos(t)$$

So when $x = \sin t = 0, \;\; t = 0,\;$ and when $x = \sin t = 1,\; t = \pi/2$.

So the final line should be evaluated as follows

$$ I =x\arcsin(x)\Big|_0^1 +\cos(t)\Big|_0^{\pi/2}$$

Comment: This certainly deserves a TU! Rectified! +1

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the bounds of the integral when you change variables (or change your variables back at the end). When $x=0, t=0$ when $x=1, t=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

It could have been way simpler (imho) if you have noted that

$$-2x=\frac d{dx}(-x^2)\implies \int\limits_0^1\frac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=-\frac12\int\limits_0^1\frac{-2x\,dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=$$

$$=\left.-\frac12\cdot 2\sqrt{1-x^2}\right|_0^1=1$$

Comment: Yea I noted that, I just wanted to do it in another way. thanks!